# Read Specific Character from NSSTRING and save them in NSDictionary (LinkedIn Api)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using Linkedin Api in my Iphone App.I want to read the Connection Names and their Profession.In First Step I read the user name and Professional by using the Following Api.

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~

It return the following String  and I convert that string in to NSDictionary .Its Work Fine.

====================================

coming string is equql to {
  "headline": "Computer Software Professional",
  "lastName": "Ahmed",
  "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=86794265&authToken=ZBFd&authType=name&trk=api*a135617*s143990*"},
  "firstName": "Umair"
}

========================================

Nsstring to NSDictionary conversion:-

Data coming from LinkedIn site

```
NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



NSLog(@"coming string is equql to %@",responseBody);

NSDictionary *profile = [responseBody objectFromJSONString];
[responseBody release];

if ( profile )
{
```

name.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
               [profile objectForKey:@"firstName"], [profile objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
headline.text = [profile objectForKey:@"headline"];
    }

The Above code Work Fine.

But when i use Connection Api.(For Linkedin Friends)
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections

I receive the following response in String.

========================================================================================
coming string is equql to {
  "values": [
    {
      "headline": "--",
      "id": "jrzlnzmKgH",
      "lastName": "ahmad",
      "pictureUrl": "http://media.linkedin.com/mpr/mprx/0_7bH7Ex4_zD3EJFYkDFRKEjehBacbMF0kD8prEjV0eIiBQ_HXiT4_XgmAM8BZVhOemkol5sXLbyGk",
      "location": {
        "name": "United Arab Emirates",
        "country": {"code": "ae"}
      },
      "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=87979190&authToken=RO5n&authType=name&trk=api*a135617*s143990*"},
      "apiStandardProfileRequest": {
        "headers": {
          "values": [{
            "name": "x-li-auth-token",
            "value": "name:RO5n"
          }],
          "_total": 1
        },
        "url": "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/jrzlnzmKgH"
      },
      "firstName": "junaid"
    },
    {
      "headline": "Field Testing Engineer at SENSYS",
      "id": "iZbYn6whQT",
      "lastName": "Ali Ayub",
      "location": {
        "name": "Pakistan",
        "country": {"code": "pk"}
      },
      "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=66010848&authToken=k_Wj&authType=name&trk=api*a135617*s143990*"},
      "apiStandardProfileRequest": {
        "headers": {
          "values": [{
            "name": "x-li-auth-token",
            "value": "name:k_Wj"
          }],
          "_total": 1
        },
        "url": "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/iZbYn6whQT"
      },
      "industry": "Government Administration",
      "firstName": "Prince"
    },
    {
      "headline": "Student at comsats",
      "id": "AZtfwY31D2",
      "lastName": "Anwar",
      "location": {
        "name": "Pakistan",
        "country": {"code": "pk"}
      },
      "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=106573059&authToken=4_ll&authType=name&trk=api*a135617*s143990*"},
      "apiStandardProfileRequest": {
        "headers": {
          "values": [{
            "name": "x-li-auth-token",
            "value": "name:4_ll"
          }],
          "_total": 1
        },
        "url": "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/AZtfwY31D2"
      },
      "industry": "Computer Networking",
      "firstName": "Irfan"
    },
    {
      "headline": "WiMAX RF Planning Engineer  at IACGRP",
      "id": "ERjOSiKbPo",
      "lastName": "Arsil",
      "pictureUrl": "http://media.linkedin.com/mpr/mprx/0_T_Ic9x0GWkhvZ7R13LHX9juCdb-ZsoI1iC0e9pDY9C6e5mpPD5RRZyMKFdtbJDo088ddJU1s5_py",
      "location": {
        "name": "Pakistan",
        "country": {"code": "pk"}
      },
      "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile?viewProfile=&key=35285050&authToken=ouYS&authType=name&trk=api*a135617*s143990*"},
      "apiStandardProfileRequest": {
        "headers": {
          "values": [{
            "name": "x-li-auth-token",
            "value": "name:ouYS"
          }],
          "_total": 1
        },
        "url": "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/ERjOSiKbPo"
      },

=====================================================

Now I want to convert it in to NsDictionary With key Value Like Firstname,Lastname etc.How can I do This.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Json Libraray for Retreive your Values.Its so Simple.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a JSON library for iPhone. One of them is the TouchJSON library, you can see [this question to learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application).